# Logging Server Name & Server IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, logging

When an exception is thrown, we log it. However, we are unable to retrieve the server name or I.P address. Not sure if this is the right way to retrieve it.

`Log.ServerName = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];`
`Log.ServerIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];`

This doesn't seem to work. It returns 'localhost' and ::1 as the I.P address.

Comment: What do you expect it should be?

Comment: We tried using ELMAH, and it returns the name of the machine and the I.P address. The development box is a remote server

Comment: Do you want the IP address of the caller or your server? If you want the IP address of your server can't you just use `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` and `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses()`?

Comment: I can try using Dns.GetHostName()

Comment: What is the context? ASP.NET or perhaps something else like WCF?

Comment: @ Thanks Daniel Kelley, your solution worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment seems like you want to log the local server name and ip address. One solution is to use [Dns.GetHostName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname.aspx) and [Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it work just as it should if you tested it from the local server in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the testing of the application on the same machine that you are running the web server on? If so, then the IPV6 loopback address and localhost are the expected results for the variables. If you send the request from another machine, then the values should be what you expect.

Alternately, the HTTPRequest.Url property will contain the client identity for the host that may be more useful if you anticipate multiple aliases for the host application.